# How do i show values that are duplicate in an array from a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, duplicates

I have an array as such:

```
let newArray = $('#TA2').val().split('\n');
```

Where `#TA2` is a `textarea`. The output from `console.log` is:

```
["542|519", "542|519", "540|500"]
```

I want to show only the values that are duplicate, so the output should be: `["542|519"]`

How do i do this using js/jquery? everything i try won't work unfortunately and i'm in need of help..
The diffrence in this question related to others is that i want my array to be dynamic with `textarea` input hence the first variable newArray that gets the values from the `textarea` to create a new array. The end-goal is to add a `<button>`, when clicked on a array should be created from the `textarea` and must only show the duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and `for..in`. Use `reduce` to create a object where keys will be `542|519` like this and it's value will be the number of occurrence. So if the value is more than 1 then it is a duplicate

```js
let dups = ["542|519", "542|519", "540|500"].reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr]) {
    acc[curr] += 1
  } else {
    acc[curr] = 1

  }

  return acc;
}, {});
for (let keys in dups) {
  if (dups[keys] > 1) {
    console.log(keys)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how do I implement newArray in let dups? For instance if the textarea values changes the output should change with the new array. I hope you understand my question